# R grid.arrange: nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE

Tags: r, gridextra

I have a problem with the function `grid.arrange`. I would like to plot a boxplot of a dataset and plot a datatable below with the minimum, mean, median and maximum values. I'm getting the following error message: nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE. Here is my code:

```
df.plot <- ggplot((Boxplot_Flaechenpotential_2_2),     aes(x=GMDKLASSE,y=Flaeche)) + 
  ylab("Flächenpotential (1000m2)") + xlab(" ") +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw() +
  ggtitle(" ") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank())


lab.df<-data.frame(lab1=c("Kleine Gemeinde","Mittlere Gemeinde","Grosse Gemeinde"),
               lab2=c("1","2","38"),
               lab3=c("55","78","176"),
               lab4=c("67","96","233"),
               lab5=c("214","443","1042"))

lab.df$lab1 <- factor(lab.df$lab1, levels=lab.df$lab1)
lab.df$lab2 <- factor(lab.df$lab2, levels=lab.df$lab2)
lab.df$lab3 <- factor(lab.df$lab3, levels=lab.df$lab3)
lab.df$lab4 <- factor(lab.df$lab4, levels=lab.df$lab4)
lab.df$lab5 <- factor(lab.df$lab5, levels=lab.df$lab5)

df.table1 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab1, y = 0,
                            label = lab1)) +
  geom_text(size = 4.5, colour = "black") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = " ") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
    axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1.2))

df.table2 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab2, y = 0,
                            label = lab2)) +
  geom_text(size = 4.5, colour = "black") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = "Tiefster Wert")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
    axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 3.0))

df.table3 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab3, y = 0,
                            label = lab3)) +
  geom_text(size = 4.5, colour = "black") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = "Mittelwert")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
    axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 3.0))

df.table4 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab4, y = 0,
                            label = lab4)) +
  geom_text(size = 4.5, colour = "black") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = "Median")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
    axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 3.0))

df.table5 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab5, y = 0,
                            label = lab5)) +
  geom_text(size = 4.5, colour = "black") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = "Höchster Wert")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
    axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 3.0))

gA <- ggplotGrob(df.plot)
gB <- ggplotGrob(df.table1)
gC <- ggplotGrob(df.table2)
gD <- ggplotGrob(df.table3)
gE <- ggplotGrob(df.table4)
gF <- ggplotGrob(df.table5)

maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gA$widths[2:3], gB$widths[2:3],         gC$widths[2:3], gD$widths[2:3], gE$widths[2:3], gF$widths[2:3])
gA$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gB$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gC$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gD$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gE$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gF$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)

grid.arrange(gA, gB, gC, gD, gE, gF, ncol=1, heights=c(5, 0.6, 0.6))
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce the error as follows:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
grid.arrange(rectGrob(), rectGrob(), rectGrob(), ncol = 1, heights = c(1, 2))
#Error: nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE
```

It's easily fixed by specifying a height for each plot:

```
grid.arrange(rectGrob(), rectGrob(), rectGrob(), ncol = 1, heights = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Or you could set `ncol = 2`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that solves the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, as the message suggests, albeit tersely, if you use the heights argument it needs to correspond to the number of rows in the layout. If you omit ncol, it will figure out the number of columns required to fit all the grobs on three rows.